# A sentence with ので

Tags: meaning

I don't understand where the verb "solve" is in this sentence.

> 誰もこの問題のでできる者はない。
> There is nobody who can solve this problem.

What does ので mean here? Isn't it suppose to mean "because of"?

Comment: Are you sure you read it right?

Comment: I am not sure..

Answer (score 1):

I am 100% sure the `問題のでできる者` part is wrong. This must be a typo of some sort.

The corrected sentence is `誰もこの問題のできる者はない。` (with only one `で`) and the verb "solve" would be the `できる` part.

But a better version would be `誰もこの問題が解ける者はない。`. Here, the verb "solve" is the `解ける` (`とける`) part.